# get all children of a parent mysql one query for 5.6

Tags: mysql-5.6

Table only has column

```
|id|Name|Parent
```

the parent being the root of the of the table

The result required

```
|Parent|child_id|Ancestral_Level
```

Child_ids All the succeeding Children where the parent

is their a way to do it on 5.6 as simple as possible?

Update

Now i just need the depth level to perent

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)

Comment: Please include your query and where you are getting stuck.

Comment: `select
        IDAccount,
        Upline 
from    (select * from TbBinary
         order by Upline, IDAccount) childaccounts,
        (select @pv := 'A') initialisation
where   find_in_set(Upline, @pv) > 0
and     @pv := concat(@pv, ',', IDAccount)`

Comment: row 1 contains IDAccount A and Upline is A.. while row 2 IDAccount B and Upline is A

Comment: i've got it working `select  IDAccount,
        name,
        Upline 
from    (select * from BinaryTable
         order by Upline, IDAccount) Sorted_Table,
        (select @pv := '19') initialisation
where   find_in_set(Upline, @pv) > 0
and     @pv := concat(@pv, ',', IDAccount)
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may find the answer you are looking for here: [Hierarchical data in MySQL: parents and children in one query](https://explainextended.com/2009/07/20/hierarchical-data-in-mysql-parents-and-children-in-one-query/)